# Chart Value of the bar

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I'm working with Chart.js and have it set up to produce a nice bar chart. Unfortunately, the default popup when you hover over the bars only shows the value of the bar. I would like the popup to display the label of each bar in the group and its value.
Do you have any examples etc?
Thank you so much!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX3jZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Information on hover can be configured. Check "interactions" and "events" in the charts.js  [documentation.](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/)